# GtkGLArea: GL_ARB_create_context_profile extension not found

Tags: opengl, gtk, gtk3, glx

I'm trying to get GTK+ 3.16's new GLArea widget to work. It is intended to provide built-in OpenGL support w/o relying on the outdated GtkGLExt/GtkGLArea projects. Since I'm not willing to update my working distribution to Gnome 3.16 just yet, I installed Fedora 22 Alpha on a virtual machine using Gnome Boxes.

Following [ebassi's blog post](https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/) I added a GLArea child to my window UI file:

```
<child>
    <object class="GtkGLArea" id="gl_drawing_area">
        <signal name="realize" handler="gl_init" swapped="yes"/>
        <signal name="unrealize" handler="gl_fini" swapped="yes"/>
        <signal name="render" handler="gl_draw" swapped="yes"/>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="hexpand">True</property>
        <property name="vexpand">True</property>
    </object>
</child>
```

and connected the signals. I should say that I'm using Vala for my UI code. The actual OpenGL code is intended to go into a C function that I would call from the `gl_draw` Vala method. For now, the three Vala functions just print their names.

Indeed, `gl_init` and `gl_fini` get called. But the GLArea widget displays this error message:

> The GLX_ARB_create_context_profile extension needed to create core profiles is not available

I also tried to run ebassi's very own [example program (GitHub)](https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example). It does not even display the UI but outputs

> glarea: Couldn't find current GLX or EGL context.

on the terminal right away.

However, running `glxinfo` tells me I got that extension installed:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
...
```

`glxgears` also runs without problems.

Moreover, I cloned the [GNOME/gtkglarea repo in Github](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkglarea), compiled it myself and ran the examples without any problems. <strike>I understand this project developed the GLArea widget before it was officially included in GTK?</strike> (I was wrong about this.)

Comment: The `glxinfo` output you have given does _not_ list `GLX_ARB_create_context_profile` as available. Your server clearly lacks support for that. Bascially, you can only use what both the client and the server support at the same time. This is also why `glxinfo` explicitely lists "GLX extensions" after "server glx extensions" and "client glx extensions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running under virtualised environments is always fairly tricky.

Even if you see the extension you may be unable to create a proper GLX context because of the requirement on the minimum version that GTK+ uses (i.e. 3.2); the llvmpipe software rasterizer in Mesa does not fully support OpenGL 3.2 because some of the required extensions are covered by patents. See [bug 744407](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744407) for the details, as well as the plan going forward.

As an aside: usually, being able to run `glxgears` is not an indication of being able to use OpenGL — except the very old, 1.x fixed pipeline API. Just like it's not an OpenGL benchmark, `glxgears` is not a good indicator of OpenGL availability, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate; in that case I will have to think about upgrading my host to Gnome 3.16. Thanks a lot for this answer and your great blog post in the first place. I'm quite quite new to OpenGL and Gtk and there's a lot about the mechanics I still don't understand. Why was I able to run the examples from the GNOME/gtkglarea repo then?

Comment: gtkglarea is an old library; the original code used GTK+ 2, and recently had a GTK+ 3 port. The port is using deprecated API, it's not integrated with the GTK drawing cycle (thus it's exploiting undefined behaviour that may break at any point), and it's still based on the deprecated legacy GL contexts. For GTK+ 3.16 we decided not to support both legacy and core GL profiles because it cannot be reliably detected what the user is going to use. Hopefully, Mesa will be fixed soon.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize it was the old GtkGLArea. It's a bit confusingly named. Thanks again. I created a new user on my machine and [installed Gnome 3.16 via JHBuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/jhbuild-and-gnome.html.en) and now it works.

Comment: @ebassi `glxgears -info | head -n5` 

 > GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
 > GL_VERSION    = 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.59
 > GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation

Pretty good indicator, but I usually run glmark2